# @ConditionalOnProperty Inner Classes of Interface implemented by Class extending NestedCondition

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So this approach may not be viable and I'm misunderstanding the construction.

I'm using Spring and I have an interface which I'd like to use for two different types of @Conditional checks.  I declare my inner classes and specify the @ConditonalOnProperty environment values I'm looking for.

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;

public interface CloudEnvironments {
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.profiles.active", havingValue = "dev")
    class IsDev {}

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.profiles.active", havingValue = "stage")
    class IsStage {}

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.profiles.active", havingValue = "prod")
    class IsProd {}
}
```

I then create my class which extends the appropriate Spring NestedCondition.  One that checks for ANY environment to match (Cloud) and one where NONE of the environments match (Local)

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AnyNestedCondition;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.NoneNestedConditions;

public class EnvironmentConditional {
    public static class AnyCloud extends AnyNestedCondition implements CloudEnvironments {
        public AnyCloud() {
            super(ConfigurationPhase.PARSE_CONFIGURATION);
        }
    }

    public static class NotCloud extends NoneNestedConditions implements CloudEnvironments {
        public NotCloud() {
            super(ConfigurationPhase.PARSE_CONFIGURATION);
        }
    }
}
```

and then I implement it in my custom DataSource

```
@Configuration
@Conditional(EnvironmentConditional.AnyCloud.class)
public class CloudDataSource {
    @Bean
    public DataSource stuff(){
        /** CODE **/
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when I run the App, when displaying all of the Conditional matches

```
- AnyNestedCondition 0 matched 0 did not (EnvironmentConditional.AnyCloud)
```

Meaning it didn't see any of the @ConditionalOnProperty checks. (I can make this work if I pull it up a level, I was curious if I could make it more DRY this way).

I've got a static inner class implementing another inner class...and it's seeming that I've gone too deep.

Can I get a nudge on my misfire in logic and if there's an approach that will allow me to have a single @ConditonalOnProperty for each environment while leveraging the NestedConditions from Spring.

Answer (score 0):

I gave a try like this and I was able to decide to match the condition.
We can also simply make use of `@Profile("cloud")` to enable profile specific beans

```
public class EnvironmentConditional {
    public static class AnyCloud extends SpringBootCondition implements CloudEnvironments {


        @Override
        public ConditionOutcome getMatchOutcome(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {

            Environment env=context.getBeanFactory().getBean(Environment.class);
            for( String profile : env.getActiveProfiles()){
                switch(profile){

                case "dev" : return new ConditionOutcome(true, "Matched"); 
                case "prod" : return new ConditionOutcome(false, "UnMatched"); 
                }
            }
            return new ConditionOutcome(true, "Matched");
        }
    }

    public static class NotCloud extends NoneNestedConditions implements CloudEnvironments {
        public NotCloud() {
            super(ConfigurationPhase.PARSE_CONFIGURATION);
        }
    }
}
```

Also have a look at this ,

**@ConditionalOnCloudPlatform** :

[Doc link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnCloudPlatform.html)

Comment: It would seem that doing this I wouldn't need the CloudEnvironments interface and instead would move the logic up a level to the getMatchOutcome.

Unfortunately this logic would be duplicated in the AnyCloud as well as the NoCloud conditional check which was what i was hoping to avoid.

Comment: well any cloud or no cloud can be determined based on the environment as I just updated my answer. Your point is valid though for one level up

Comment: @milk also have a look at ConditionalOnCloudPlatform https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnCloudPlatform.html